# If $a^k\equiv b\bmod p$ then $a^{k+1}\equiv ab\bmod p$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

If $a^k\equiv b\bmod p$ then $a^{k+1}\equiv ab\bmod p$.

Prove using the proposition, If $a\equiv b\bmod n$ and $c\equiv d\bmod n$ then $ac\equiv bd\bmod n$.

Comment: Given that there is already a hint for this, why haven’t you tried to use it?  If you have tried to use it, please record your efforts in the question itself.

Comment: Have you tried anything using the hint ??